# Blank page when opening an HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I followed Derek Banas' YouTube tutorial on creating a Tetris game. But when I open my HTML file ("Tetris.html") on Google Chrome, it just opens a blank page and nothing else.

I've tried updating Chrome but I have the latest version. I have also tried openning older HTML files, without issues. My CSS, JS and HTML files are located in the same folder.

HTML file ("Tetris.html"):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">       
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
        <title>JavaScript Tetris</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyle.css">
        <script src="TetrisBasic.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id='my-canvas'></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS file ("mainstyle.css"):

```
body {
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
}
#my-canvas {
    background: #fff;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

I'm not including my JS file ("TetrisBasic.js") since I don't think it has any issues. Tell me if I should otherwise.

Comment: Well, the code you've provided won't show anything visible on screen. You've got an empty page with an untouched canvas. What would you expect to see at this point and why? (I expect to see nothing and get exactly that - works as designed. The design sounds like it might contain a flaw)

Comment: Right click on the page and select "inspect", which will bring up Chrome's inspection display.  Then select the "console" tab to see if there are any error messages.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's blank because your canvas has no color. The provided color in css is #fff. So, if you aims to see the canvas in your page, you need to change the background or put some border color to your #my-canvas class. Something like thats:

```
#my-canvas {
    background: #000;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```